# Custom Loading Screen with jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hey i use jquery/jquery mobile and phonegap for developing an app communicating to an webservice. I want a screen which will be displayed during something will be loaded (e.g. an ajax request). I looked for the jQm-function **$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg** but this does not block the screen for user interaction. So i build an own screen, actually a simple div, which i make visible, calling a function. This works pretty well when i test the site in browser, but when i load it to my android phone it does not work anymore. Have anybody an idea? or had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try blockUI?

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/